# Is there a prime $p>7$ of the form $F_n\pm 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_n$ be the $n$-th fibonacci number.

For $n\le 60\ 000$ , the largest prime of the form $F_n-1$ or $F_n+1$ is $7=F_6-1$

> Is there another prime of one of the forms ?

It must have more than $12\ 000$ digits.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24F_n%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24F_n-1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1), there's [For $n\ge4,$ prove that $F_n+1$ is not prime, where $F_n$ is $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number.](/q/2779398), where [Sil's answer](/a/2779496) gives a more general solution, with it referencing an [AoPS thread's post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1249887p8924937) containing a proof confirming there is no such prime $p \gt 7$.